# Projection from array size throwing error for undefined array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I'm trying to do the following:

```
for i in range(5):
    collection.insert({'a': ['1' for j in range(i)]} if i else {})

# the collection now contains 5 documents: one with only an _id field
# and four with an _id and an array of different sizes.]

list(m.aggregate([{'$project': {'a': 1, 'amt': {'$size': '$a'}}}]))
```

However, this throws an OperationFailure since $a isn't defined for the empty document.

How do I tell Mongo to give me a 0 for the empty document? Can I fall back to an empty array if field `a` is undefined during projection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the array exists (though not using $exists) and otherwise output 0, like so:

```
{
    '$project': {
        'a': 1, 
        'amt': {
            $cond: [ {$gt: ["$a", null]}, {'$size': '$a'}, 0 ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is with the [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) operator.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "a": 1, 
        "amt": { "$size": { "$ifNull": [ "$a", [] ] } }
    }}
])
```